# Retrieving large vol of data using AJAX for graph

Tags: javascript, json, graph

I am designing a server which provides data/info to a web client, as well as to a mobile client (phase 2).  The data will populate a graph; imaging plotting the price of a stock over 5 years (show min/max/avg) for each day.

1] If I send 3000 data points to a client, thats a lof of data to send, and then plot.  Conversly, if I build the graphic on the server, I can send a PNG to the client.  Which is better?

2] Is it a bad practice to plot every point over 5 years?  Is there a way for MySQL to average 5 data points (days) at a time and return that instead?

Still in the design phase, but I realize this decision will really affect app performance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you estimate the amount of data you'll about to send? 3000 data points can be anything between 12K (4 bytes per `float`) and 100K (timestamp + value in textual format). While 12K is nothing, 100K is significant, especially for mobile devices.

Processing time is also important. Generating data on the server using some lower-level language and returning PNG will be much more efficient compared to generating chart on canvas.

But you should think about resolution of your chart. If you want to plot 3000 points you need at least 3000 pixels horizontally. Biggest screen these days reach [2560 pixels width](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution), which means you'll never be able to display all the data, you'll have to hide some points. It's much worse on mobile. Strive fro 200-300 pixels width, and at least two times less data points.

That being said, I suggest the following approach:

- compute average and return no more than 100-200 data points to the browser (average has to be smart so that you don't loose some interesting extremes).
- use one of dozens of JavaScript charting libraries on the browser
- once you need more detailed information, user can zoom in the chart, which will ask server for data in higher resolution.

Comment: I'm leaning towards returning a graphic, but then I shift the burden to the backend for computing running average, or average every 5 data points.  Is there a MySQL command to average every 5 point and return that instead?